# Ruby Monk Number Shuffle - comparison of solutions

Tags: ruby

I was doing this Ruby Monk challenge http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/154-permutations and came up with this solution:

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  string_rep = number.to_s
  ary = string_rep.split('').permutation(number.to_s.length).to_a

  result = []

  ary.each do |i|
    x = i.join.to_i
    result << x
  end

  return result.sort
end
```

Meanwhile, here's Ruby Monk's solution:

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  no_of_combinations = number.to_s.size == 3 ? 6 : 24
  digits = number.to_s.split(//)
  combinations = []
  combinations << digits.shuffle.join.to_i while combinations.uniq.size!=no_of_combinations
  combinations.uniq.sort
end
```

I sense Ruby Monk's solution is more ruby-style but I'd like to better understand why.
Could you share your thoughts and give some hints?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add the problem within your question- not just a link.

Comment: `return` keyword not required.

Comment: Thanks, will bear in mind to post the full problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are calling `number.to_s` twice even though you created a variable (i.e. `string_rep`) that contains that exact value. No need to make a method call multiple times.
2. As someone mentioned, it's a newbie mistake to create a new array and then append to that array when you can simply use the `map` or `collect` methods (they do the same thing). So the code would be better if it read `result = ary.map {|i| i.join.to_i}`
3. No need to type out `return result.sort`. Ruby returns the last command by default, so you can simply omit the `return` directive and write `result.sort`.

Also, the example solution makes the numbers unique. Are you doing the same?

Comment: No problem, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby Monk's solution is bad programming but the style is alright. Your solution is acceptable but the style can be improved.

Anyway, this can be done with a one-liner :

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  number.to_s.split('').permutation.to_a.collect {|a| a.join.to_i}.sort
end
```

Edited: `sort` is needed because `permutation`  [makes no guarantees about the order](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-permutation).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is "non-ruby" is...

```
result = []

ary.each do |i|
  x = i.join.to_i
  result << x
end
```

It's a typical "new to ruby" mistake to use `each` and add to an array on each iteration, when the method `map` will return an array automatically.

```
result = ary.map {|i| i.join.to_i }
```

Also note we didn't need the intermediate result `x`, and as the block is relatively short we're better served with `{}` instead of `do end`